# Why is this function overload with argument type conversion ambiguous?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, overloading

Can someone explain how this function overload resolution is ambiguous?

Given:

```
/// This type *contains* a @c T.
template< typename T >
class User_Type
{
public:
    /// This <em>conversion constructor</em> is a key part of it's API;
    ///   it won't likely change.
    User_Type( T const & ar_data )
      : m_data( ar_data )
    {}
private:
    T m_data;
};

/// @c some_value is just a templated function that generates a @c T.
template< typename T > T some_value();
template<> char some_value();
template<> int some_value();

/// This overloaded, non-templated function represents some third-party
///   code somewhere else; it's API can't be changed.
void other_function( User_Type< char > const& );
void other_function( User_Type< int > const& );

/// This is user-code.  It's contents exercise some aspect of the 'User_Type' API.
///   This code can change.
template< typename T >
void function()
{
    other_function( some_value< T >() ); /* AMBIGUOUS CALL */

    User_Type< T > user_var = some_value< T >(); /* UNAMBIGUOUS CONVERSION */
    other_function( user_var ); /* UNAMBIGUOUS CALL */
}
template void function< char >();
template void function< int >();
```

and compiling with `g++-4.9 -Wall -Wextra`, I receive the following errors:

```
In instantiation of ‘void function() [with T = char]’:
    error: call of overloaded ‘other_function(char)’ is ambiguous
    note: candidates are:
    note: void other_function(const User_Type<char>&)
    note: void other_function(const User_Type<int>&)
In instantiation of ‘void function() [with T = int]’:
    error: call of overloaded ‘other_function(int)’ is ambiguous
    note: candidates are:
    note: void other_function(const User_Type<char>&)
    note: void other_function(const User_Type<int>&)
```

I expect the best match for `other_function( char )` to be `other_function( User_Type< char > const& )`, and the best match for `other_function( int )` to be `other_function( User_Type< int > const& )`.

I understand a type conversion must take place for each argument to `other_function`.  I'd expect `char` to `User_Type< char >` to be a better choice than `char` to `User_Type< int >`, which could be allowed by `char` to `int` promotion.  I'd expect `int` to `User_Type< int >` to be a better choice than `int` to `User_type< char >`, which could be allowed by `int` to `char` conversions.

Additionally, if I create a local `User_Type< T > user_var` from a `T`, then I can unambiguously call `other_function( user_var )`.  Semantically, this should be equivalent to the first, original statement.

Comment: I feel like I've run into this before, but I'm drawing a blank. I believe it has to do with the order of which templates are evaluated, i.e. the return type for some_value<T> is not deduced until after function is processed, and thus it is an ambiguous call. The same reason why you couldn't add a public `typedef T some_type;` to `User_Type<T>`, and have the compiler figure out that `User_Type<T>::some_type` is a type without fully qualifying it, i.e. `typename User_Type<T>::some_type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no exact match for `other_function(char)` or `other_function(int)`,

```
other_function( some_value< T >() );
```

must implicitly convert its argument to match one of:

```
void other_function( User_Type< char > const& );
void other_function( User_Type< int > const& );
```

but `User_Type<char>` has ctor `User_Type<char>( char const& )`, which accepts an `int`, and `User_Type<int>` has ctor `User_Type<int>( int const& )`, which accepts a `char`.

Your conversions fall under the ranking of "User-Defined conversion sequence," and since both of those conversions are possible, both are included in the overload set with equal ranking. Hence the call is ambiguous. (See 13.3.3.2 *Ranking implicit conversion sequences* in the standard for more information.)

Comment: Wouldn't the conversion sequence of `User_Type< char >( char const& )` have a better rank than `User_Type< char >( int const& )`?  The second requires a conversion of the argument, ( with loss of precision ).  The first is a direct match.

Comment: I've tried to read §13.3.3.x before; I've never fully groked it.

Comment: Not quite. The wording from the standard says "User-defined conversion sequence U1 is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence U2 if they contain *the same user- defined conversion function or constructor or aggregate initialization* and the second standard conversion sequence of U1 is better..." In this case you have two UD-conversions with *different* constructors. If `User_Type` was itself a type with `User_Type(int)` and `User_Type(char)` ctors there would be a disambiguation..

Comment: Unfortunately, `User_Type` must be templated; I'm not going to try to do type-erasure.
For context, `User_Type` will *contain* an instance of `T`.

Comment: I've updated the question with comments describing which parts are "fixed", and which parts can change.

Comment: If the question is "how do I disambiguate this call given these constraints," you must specify the type of the argument, like `other_function( User_Type<T>{some_value< T >()} );`.

Comment: It's just taken a bit for §13.3.3.2 ¶5 for UD-conversions to sink in.

Comment: I'm trying to enumerate various ways my `User_Type` API can be used by a client.  I was able to get the implicit conversion from a `T` to `User_Type<T>` as an argument for a non-templated, non-overloaded function-call, and as an argument for a templated, non-overloaded function (as you have to specify the template-function type at the call site. )  I was hoping for implicit conversions to non-templated, overloaded functions to also work.  Ah well, another non-intuitive gotcha to remember.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of adding `template< typename T > User_Type< T > make_user_type( T const & );`.  Then the call `other_function( User_Type<T>( some_value< T >() ) ) )` can become `other_function( make_user_type( some_value< T >() ) )`.  It's a bit more verbose, but it requires `<T>` one less time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is trying to pick an overload based on qualifying conversions.  I can take out some of the templates and get the same result:

```
class User_Type_char
{
public:
    User_Type_char(char const &) {}
};

class User_Type_int
{
public:
    User_Type_int(int const &) {}
};

void other_function( User_Type_char const& );
void other_function( User_Type_int const& );

template< typename T >
void function()
{
    other_function( 'a' ); /* AMBIGUOUS CALL */
}
```

The problem is that there is no perfect match in the overload list, so we start checking for conversions.  In turn, though, `char` and `int` have implicit conversion available so it isn't clear which one you want.

If for this same code I change the constructor of the first class

```
class User_Type_char
{
public:
    User_Type_char(const char*) {}
};
```

Now the same call becomes unambiguous and calls the User_Type_int version.

Comment: Well, the interface of 'User_Type' is fixed; I'm trying to determine what all the "expected" uses of this API would be.  I was hoping implicit conversion from `T` to `User_Type<T>` via a function argument would be supported; this implicit conversion happens for a function's return type.  :-/

Comment: I've updated the question with comments describing which parts are "fixed", and which parts can change.

Comment: The point of my answer wasn't to suggest a new interface but to show that the issue is related to type conversion and not to templates (as then was better explained by hs_).  AFAICT you can't do overload resolution two steps removed like this.  You need to separate out the steps of type conversion and overload resolution.  You could add a function template in between that adds User_Type<> like `template<class T> void call_other_function(T const & val) { other_function(User_Type<T>(val)); }`

Comment: Ahh, wrapping overloaded functions with templated functions.  Hmm, that could work, if a user really needed to call overloaded functions frequently.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of adding `template< typename T > User_Type< T > make_user_type( T const & );`.  Then the ambiguous call `other_function( some_value< T >() ) )` can become `other_function( make_user_type( some_value< T >() ) )`.  It's a bit more verbose, but it's better than wrapping overloaded functions in a set of templated functions.